# How can i verify a user registartion using sms verification?

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

i want to create a user registration by sms verification. after entering mobile number in my website(php) will send(and also will be stored to database against user id) a random 4 or 6 digit code to users number. then user will have to enter that code to my websites confirmation page. then it will check that code with the stored code in the database. if it matches then user is verified. **I want to know what will be the cheapest sms service i can use in india ?** **if there are any free ervice like this then it will be good(atleast for testing).**

Comment: http://kit19.com/ //try this

Comment: These are questions which are offtopic on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many message API providers in india. If you are looking for free service then it is not possible now a days. As per my knowledge and experience you can go with Idea cellular message Api. It is very fast and efficient in india. I dont know adjuct cost for that but you can find it in idea official website.

Every Api provider gives you some free messages for testing purpose so that you can check that api with your code. If you need any further help then contact me.